# Searching in JIRA: items that do not have a text in comments

Tags: jira

Hi there I am trying to use the quick search in JIRA to search for all the items that do not have "hello" text in any comment.

I tried using:
comment !~ "hello"

but it didn't work. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: comment !~ "hello" should work. It might take a while though

Comment: It shows me this msg -> Unable to parse the text 'comment !~ "hello"' for field 'text'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the quick search feature for this. The quick search will try to figure out your input, and if it receives text (as opposed to issue id), it will search for it freely. When you type `comment !~ "hello"` in the quick search, notice you get to the search page, and the search term is parsed as `text ~ "comment !~ \"hello\""`.

If you go to the search page instead of using the quick search and type the phrase `comment !~ "hello"` in the filter, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, the comment !~ "hello" will not work as expected in a filter.

Instead use a positive sub-query / filter and subtract it's results from your final query.

filter "Closed and approved"

```
status in (rejected, closed) and comment ~ "close approved"
```

filter "Closed but NOT approved"

```
reporter = currentUser() and status in (rejected, closed) and filter != "Closed and approved"
```